# Сортировка постов и пагинация на php как вывести через $_GET

Tags: php, сортировка, get, pagination

Есть такой код:

```
    <a href="?r=showpost&page=0"><b class="pagination">1</b></a>

    <?php for($i = 2; $i <= $this->count[0][0]/2; $i++):?>

    <a href="?r=showpost&page=<?php echo $i;?>"><b class="pagination"><?php echo ceil($i);?></b></a>

    <?php endfor;?>

    <a href="?r=showpost&sort=autor">AutorName> </a>

    <a href="?r=showpost&sort=autor_email">AutorEmail </a>
```

если я нажму на страницу то url будет такой ?r=showpost&page=1;
если сортировать посты то url будет такой ?r=showpost&sort=name;

а я хочу получать через GET и то и другое

типа так ?r=showpost&sort=name&page=1;

что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов несколько. Или писать функцию на php, которая будет проверять параметры урла и формировать их, или использовать url.js плагин, который тоже формирует урлы из параметров. Из практики мне намного удобней стал url.js. который легко добавляет параметры в урл и работает с ними.

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто не передаете в ссылке page:

```
a href="?r=showpost&sort=autor<?php echo $_GET['page'] ? '&page='.$_GET['page'] : '' ?>">AutorName /a
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, Артем, все заработало. Голова совсем уже не думает.